# Почему объект fstream выводит мусор

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string buff = "";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(866);
    string path = "text.txt";
    fstream file(path, ios_base::in | ios_base::app);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        
        file.seekg(0, fstream::beg);

        cout << "File opened!\n";
        file << "\n";
        
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            buff = " ";
            file >> buff;
            cout << buff << '\n';

        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File is not opend!";
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

На выход в консоли получаю File opened! И множество `HНН...`
Происходит все это из-за того что я пытаюсь создать новую строку в файле, чтобы в последствии дописать туда мой новый текст.
Почему `file << "\n";` вызывает такую бурную реакцию программы и как мне реализовать дописывание в новую строку без этого мусора?

Comment: а что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать этой строкой: `file << "\n";`? У вас же файл открыт на чтение

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я объявил этот объект на чтение и на запись в конец файла, указав вторым аргументом  ios_base::in | ios_base::app

Comment: `while (!file.eof())` - эх...

Comment: надо сбросить буфер file.flush();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут на самом деле сломано почти все.
Но проблема именно с мусором - в записи и чтении из одного и того же потока без сброса буфера `file.flush();` между ними.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать где почитать о том как правильно реализовывать работу с потоком fstream более подробно, чтобы это все починить?

Comment: @SeeNax Ну можно [доки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) почитать, но на практике io потоки из стандартной библиотеки используются разве что учебных и / или отладочный целей. Так что правильней с ними не работать совсем.

Comment: А что тогда использовать вместо потоков из стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Ничего, она в этом плане бесполезна.

Comment: В смысле ничего? Как тогда прочитать файл?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Посредством системного API.

Comment: Но это же не кроссплатформенно. А чем собственно плохи стандартные потоки? Скорость?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Это вроде избитая тема. У них отвратительный дизайн, в одном флаконе намешали бинарный / текстовый / форматируемый ввод - вывод, обработку ошибок с-style и с помощью исключений, кривая иерархия классов и посредственная производительность. Вон был тред, где их поливают: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753060/who-architected-designed-cs-iostreams-and-would-it-still-be-considered-wel